# How to create an association between devise user model and new model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I can easily do singnin and singup process in my application but I am not able to understand how to pass `user_id` in my new model. After integrating devise successfully I followed the following steps:

Generate new model with the name of book

```
rails generate model books name:string users:references
```

It generated `book` class in `models` folder along with `migration` class.

## Model class

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

## Migration class

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :books do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

Now, I add

```
has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
```

in `user` model class to make a proper `one to many` association.

After creating these classes I run `rake db:migrate` and it created a new schema in the project. After creating schema I wrote `seed` file to confirm whether my database is working or not. It was working fine. I can see the new entries in my `Book` and `user` table along with `user_id` in `Book` table.

## Routes class

```
sampleApplicationUI::Application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users
 resources :books, except: [:edit]
end
```

Now, I added a `book_controller` class and here is the code:

## Book controller class

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

 def index
  @book = Book.all
 end

def new
 @book = Book.new
end

def create
 @book = Book.new(filtered_params)
 if @book.save
   redirect_to action: 'index'
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end

private
def filtered_params
 params.require(:book).permit(:name, :user_id)
end
....
```

## books/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @book, as: :book, url: book_path do |f|  %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Name %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I followed some blogs and they were mentioning to do following changes in `book_controller` class to access `user_id` and save into `book` table:

## changes in book controller class

```
def new
  @book = Book.new(user: current_user)
end
```

but here I am getting `No variable defined current_user` :(

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here and How can i access `user.user_id` in `book controller` class.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you added :user_id to your strong params?

Comment: Adding code for strong params as well

Comment: try to change your new action to @book = current_user.books.build

Comment: Still throwing "cannot find current_user".

Comment: Is devise gem installed properly. I think it is because I can see new entries in my database in user table. right?

Comment: In your create action change it to: @book = current_user.books.build(filtered_params)

Comment: Ah! It works this time :) Can you please explain it

Comment: I recommend reading the guides for associations. I've included the belongs to reference that talks about build: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller's create method

**Book controller class**

```
def create
 @book = current_user.books.build(filtered_params)
 if @book.save
   redirect_to action: 'index'
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In books/new.html.erb, add the following line before <%= f.submit ____ %>:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```